# Discord.Py adding reactions to an embeded message

Tags: python, discord

So I am trying to add three different reactions (emojis), to a message that the bot has sent in a text channel.

The user fills in a form in their DM, and the message then get sent into a text-channel called "admin-bug", the admins of the server can then react to three different emojis:

- fixed
- will not be fixed
- not-a-bug

And then, depending on what emoji the admin press on, the message will be transferred to a text channel.

But! I can't seem to figure out how you actually add the reactions to the message itself, I have done a bunch of googling, but can't find the answer.

code:

`````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = '---'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!!')

reactions = [":white_check_mark:", ":stop_sign:", ":no_entry_sign:"]


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready.')


@bot.command()
async def bug(ctx, desc=None, rep=None):
    user = ctx.author
    await ctx.author.send('```Please explain the bug```')
    responseDesc = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author, timeout=300)
    description = responseDesc.content
    await ctx.author.send('````Please provide pictures/videos of this bug```')
    responseRep = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author, timeout=300)
    replicate = responseRep.content
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Bug Report', color=0x00ff00)
    embed.add_field(name='Description', value=description, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Replicate', value=replicate, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name='Reported By', value=user, inline=True)
    adminBug = bot.get_channel(733721953134837861)
    await adminBug.send(embed=embed)
    # Add 3 reaction (different emojis) here

bot.run(TOKEN)
`````

Answer (score 4):

`Messagable.send` returns the message it sends. So you can add reactions to it using that message object. Simply, you have to use a variable to define the message you sent by the bot.

```py
embed = discord.Embed(title="Bug report")
embed.add_field(name="Name", value="value")
msg = await adminBug.send(embed=embed)
```

You can use `msg` to add reactions to that specific message

```py
await msg.add_reaction("")
```

Read the discord.py documentation for detailed information.

[`Message.add_reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20message#discord.Message.add_reaction)

Answer (score 1):

The discord.py docs have an FAQ post about adding reactions, it has multiple exampes and an indepth description, furthermore `Messageable.send` returns the message send so you can use `Message.add_reaction` on that. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/neo-docs/faq.html#how-can-i-add-a-reaction-to-a-message

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the embed as a variable, in this way you can add a reaction.

```
message = await adminBug.send(embed=embed)  # save embed as "message"
await message.add_reaction('xxx')           # add reaction to "message"
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you explained how this helps solve the problem. The original poster might have solved their problem by now, so please edit your answer thinking of how to best add value to the people who will have a similar question and find this answer in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure because I use nextcord (and it worked), but I think this can work :

```
@bot.command
async def testembed(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Test !', description='This is a test embed !')
    msg = await ctx.send("", embed=embed)
    msg = msg.fetch()   # Notice this line ! It's important !
    await msg.add_reaction('emoji_id')
```