# Add reaction to message bot sent - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Simply put, I am trying to add two reactions to a bots message. So far I haven't gotten the bot to react to its own message at all.

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents=intents)

@bot.command(pass_context  = True)
async def rnick(ctx, *, nick, **message):
    embed=discord.Embed(color=embed_color)
    embed.add_field(name="****", value="*******************", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="*********", value="******", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="*******",value="*****", inline=True)
    embed.set_footer(text=str(ctx.author.id) + "  •  " + ct)
    await bot.get_channel(moderator_channel).send(embed=embed)
    await message.add_reaction("✅") # Here
    await message.add_reaction("❌") # and here
```

I've tried using `message.add_reaction()`, `bot.message.add_reaction()`, `ctx.message.add_reaction()` (which adds both reactions to the command message), and even `client.message.add_reaction()` no to avail.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62958944/discord-py-adding-reactions-to-an-embeded-message

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.Py adding reactions to an embeded message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62958944/discord-py-adding-reactions-to-an-embeded-message)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to react to a message sent by your own bot within that command, you must assign the message to a variable. And then use the `add_reaction` method on it (the variable previously assigned).

Here's an example, using your own piece of code:

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents=intents)

@bot.command(pass_context  = True)
async def rnick(ctx, *, nick, **message):
    embed=discord.Embed(color=embed_color)
    embed.add_field(name="****", value="*******************", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="*********", value="******", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="*******",value="*****", inline=True)
    embed.set_footer(text=str(ctx.author.id) + "  •  " + ct)
    rsp = await bot.get_channel(moderator_channel).send(embed=embed)
    await rsp.add_reaction("✅") # Here
    await rsp.add_reaction("❌") # and here
```